# Javascript not working on some browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript like following acting bizarre. Following works fine on my development machine in all three browsers chrome, FF and safari. But when I checked on anyone else machine browsers this value update does not work at all. Does anyone know how would I able to replicate this issue on my local ?

my browser test

Browser name = Chrome
Full version = 51.0.2704.103
Major version = 51
navigator.appName = Netscape
navigator.userAgent = Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36

```
jQuery(function(){

  $(document).on("click", "#history span", function() {
    var field_id = $(this).attr('history-id');
    $('#'+field_id).val('some new value');
  })
});
```

Comment: the code looks ok, maybe you should try to add some console.log to see where is going wrong. Maybe the Dom is not finished load  and onready (JQuery()) is not executing.

Comment: Is this the only code in the page? Should probably use `data-` attribute but irregardless what is shown is nothing that should be inconsistent across browsers or operating systems. What errors get thrown in consoles? My guess is something wrong connecting to resources. Dev tools console and network is where to look first

Comment: no errors throwing on console. When I deployed this to a staging environment it does not work on any browsers other than my development. it just don't update the text field. It is bit bizzare which I had no idea how to replicate this on my local as it works for me

Comment: Are you saying that the missing parenthesis does not fix the issue?

Comment: it was a mistake while i was typing. yes it works only in a particular browser

Answer (score 3):

You are missing an ending parenthesis

```
jQuery(function(){

  $(document).on("click", "#body", function() {
    console.log('sup world!')
  }) // ending paren
});
```

Comment: note however that it wouldn't work anywhere if this wasn't a typo.